# Query com data no sql inclui o dia em questão?

Tags: sql, python, datetime

Estou com uma duvida em questão dos dias exatos que as SQL incluem, e meu sistema uma vez por dia realiza a seguinte consulta no sistema:

```
SELECT id,nome FROM products WHERE 
    created_date between \'"+last_date+"\' and \'" + now+"\'
```

**Onde**

*data de hoje:*

```
now = date.fromordinal(date.today().toordinal()).strftime("%m/%d/%y")
```

*data da ultima vez que a consulta foi realizada:*

`last_date = open('/home/data_query','r').read().replace('\n',' ')`

*e no final ele irá atualizar o* `last_date` *para a próxima execução*

```
open('/home/data_query','w').write(now)
```

*bem o código ficou assim:*

```
def atualiza():
    now = date.fromordinal(date.today().toordinal()).strftime("%m/%d/%y")
    last_date = open('/home/data_query','r').read().replace('\n',' ')
    cur.execute("SELECT id, nome FROM products WHERE created_date between \'"
                 +last_date+"\' and \'" + now+"\'")
    rows = fetchall()
    products = []
    for row in rows:
        products.append([row[0],row[1]])

    open('/home/data_query','w').write(now)

    return products
```

Mas estou com duvida se realmente a forma de fiz essa manipulação de datas está certa, pois não sei se o sql inclui os dados que foram incluídos na data em questão.

Talvez alguém vai sugerir eu pesquisar em apenas um dia `created_data = hoje`, mas como as vezes posso não executar em um dia devido a manutenção ou algo do gênero, quando o script voltar a executar ele deve recuperar esses dias perdidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua resposta: O operador "between" é inclusivo - tanto o valor máximo quanto o mínimo estão inclusos na faixa de pesquisa.

Agora - esse aí não é o melhor jeito de fazer uma pesquisa por data - 
são alguns pontos que dá para acertar - seu código vai ficar mais fácil de escrever, mais fácil de manter e menos suscetível a invasão por sql injection.

Primeiro: Python sempre teve uma série de opções para interpolar dados nas strings. Agora com Python 3.6, temos as "f strings" que tornam isso ainda mais fácil - mas mesmo antes tinhamos os operadores `%` e o `.format` - então concatenar valores de variáveis fechando a string, usando o `+` é algo que nunca foi necessário. Só não vou dar um exemplo já por que para formatação de queries em SQL na verdade não usamos nem isso.

Segundo: Queries de SQL compostas com dados históricamente são um dos principais vetores de vulnerabilidade para as chamadas "sql injections" - Nesse caso específico, as datas vem de um arquivo sob seu controle e do próprio sistema, então provavelmente não são vetores de ataque. mas no caso de dados entrados pelo usuário, sanitizar os "\'" e escapes que podem permitir a inserção de uma outra query "clandestina" dentro da query tem alguns edge cases, e pode ser não trivial. Por isso, em Python, *todos* os drivers de banco de dados tem um esquema de inserirem os parâmetros na query para você. Isso é feito de forma automática, e o driver insere mesmo os `'` em votla dos dados. A única coisa é que dependendo do driver, a sintaxe usada para substituição pode variar 
 - cheuqe a sessão `paramstyle` 
 em `https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/ e a documentação do driver de SQL que você está usando (já que você não menciona qual é)

A terceira coisa é que a maior parte dos drivers de SQL aceitam objetos `date` do próprio Python - assim, você não precisa se preocupar com qual formato as datas vão estar representadas se forem strings. 
Alias, dependendo do banco SQL,datas são comaparadas internamnete como strings (acho que em quase todos) e o formato `%m/%d/%Y` americano é nada propício para esse tipo de comparação - já que o dia do mês vai influenciar mais que o ano. (Assim, 03/10/2017 vem depois de  03/15/2014). Em t.i. e bancos de dados a representação mais usual de datas é `yyyy-mm-dd`, já que nesse caso a comparação como string mantém a mesma ordem que a comparação como data

Dito tudo isso, crio uma tabela com datas no SQLITE e crio uma query fazendo uso dessas guias de estilo, para exemplo:

```
from datetime import date
import sqlite3
from pprint import pprint

conn = sqlite3.connect(":")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE teste (id INT PRIMARY KEY, nome VARCHAR, data DATE)""")

for i in range(1, 5):
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO teste VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (i, "nome de teste %d" % i, date(2017, 8, i)))

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM teste WHERE data BETWEEN ? and ?", (date(2017, 8, 2), date(2017, 8, 4)))

pprint(list(cursor.fetchall()))
```

(compare a linha que contém o "SELECT" com o seu exemplo, e veja a quantidade de símbolos a menos pra se digitar dentro da query)

E a saída é:

```
[(2, u'nome de teste 2', u'2017-08-02'),
 (3, u'nome de teste 3', u'2017-08-03'),
 (4, u'nome de teste 4', u'2017-08-04')]
```

(isso por que usei o sqlite, em que o driver só simula uma coluna de data que não existe internamente no banco. Em mysql, postgresql, e outros vão retornar um objeto "date" também quando eu fizer um select, e não uma string)